# Take input for treemap using json objects not to read from csv file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, treemap

I'm trying to build a Zoomable TreeMap using d3 js. I need to take an array of JSON objects from the server and pass it to tha treeMap and let the treemap handle it. But in doing so I'm not able to parse it

Here's my code for the tremap:

```
$rootScope.loadTreeMap = function(path_to_data,dom_element_to_append_to){

        var w = $(dom_element_to_append_to).width() - 80,
            h = 800 - 180,
            x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
            color = d3.scale.category20c(),
            root,
            node;
            console.log("W" + w);
            console.log("h " + h);

        var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
            .round(false)
            .size([w, h])
            .sticky(true)
            .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

        var svg = d3.select(dom_element_to_append_to).append("div")
            .attr("class", "chart")
            .style("width", w + "px")
            .style("height", h + "px")
          .append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
          .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");

        d3.json(path_to_data, function(data) {

            node = root = data;

          var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
              .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

          var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
              .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "cell")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
              .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

          cell.append("svg:rect")
              .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

          cell.append("svg:text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
              .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

          d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

          d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
            treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
            zoom(node);
          });
        });

        function size(d) {
          return d.size;
        }

        function count(d) {
          return 1;
        }

        function zoom(d) {
          var kx = w / d.dx, ky = h / d.dy;
          x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
          y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

          var t = svg.selectAll("g.cell").transition()
              .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

          t.select("rect")
              .attr("width", function(d) { return kx * d.dx - 1; })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return ky * d.dy - 1; })

          t.select("text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return kx * d.dx / 2; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return ky * d.dy / 2; })
              .style("opacity", function(d) { return kx * d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

          node = d;
          d3.event.stopPropagation();
        }

    }
```

`

Basically it is working fine if I load the data from a csv file stored in my system, but I want to read an array of objects from the server and then build the graph on it.

Basically here's my function which reads from the file and parses the JSON objects:

```
d3.json(path_to_data, function(data) {
            /*console.log("data");
            console.log(data);
            console.log("data");
            data = JSON.parse(inputData);
            console.log(data);*/
            node = root = data;

          var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
              .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

          var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
              .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "cell")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
              .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

          cell.append("svg:rect")
              .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

          cell.append("svg:text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
              .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

          d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

          d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
            treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
            zoom(node);
          });
        });
```

But I want to do something different like

```
node = root = inputdata  ;   here input data is array of json objects fetched from server
var nodes = treemap.nodes(root).filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });
var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured the solution to this just remove the d3.csv function ( but don't remove the body of function as your graph will generate with the body of functions only) and pass your own variable conatining the JSON objects as required by the graphs type. This will work in approximately all graphs in which data is taken through d3.csv or d3.json  here's a working code

```
$rootScope.loadTreeMap = function(path_to_data,dom_element_to_append_to){

    var w = $(dom_element_to_append_to).width() - 80,
        h = 800 - 180,
        x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
        color = d3.scale.category20c(),
        root,
        node;
        console.log("W" + w);
        console.log("h " + h);

    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .round(false)
        .size([w, h])
        .sticky(true)
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

    var svg = d3.select(dom_element_to_append_to).append("div")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .style("width", w + "px")
        .style("height", h + "px")
      .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");

   /* d3.json(path_to_data, function(data) {*/
      remove the above line and insert your own JSON object variable like 
      data = inputData(your own JSON variable)

        node = root = data;

      var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
          .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

      var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
          .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "cell")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
          .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

      cell.append("svg:rect")
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

      cell.append("svg:text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

      d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

      d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
        treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
        zoom(node);
      });
    });

    function size(d) {
      return d.size;
    }

    function count(d) {
      return 1;
    }

    function zoom(d) {
      var kx = w / d.dx, ky = h / d.dy;
      x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
      y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

      var t = svg.selectAll("g.cell").transition()
          .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

      t.select("rect")
          .attr("width", function(d) { return kx * d.dx - 1; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return ky * d.dy - 1; })

      t.select("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return kx * d.dx / 2; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return ky * d.dy / 2; })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { return kx * d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

      node = d;
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }

}
```